# Cauchy's root test for series divergence

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Just a question regarding determining the divergent in this example :$$\sum{ 1 \over \sqrt {n(n+1)}} $$ is divergent. It explains the reason by saying that $a_n$ > $1 \over n+1$. If I am not wrong it uses the root test but should not we have the $a_n \ge 1$ but how does their reasoning assure us this exactly?

Comment: Root Test is inconclusive for this series.

Answer (score 5):

It just used the comparison  test, as the summand
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{n(n + 1)}} \geq \frac{1}{\sqrt{(n + 1)^2}} = \frac{1}{n + 1} $$
and 
$$\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{n + 1} = \sum_{n = 2}^\infty \frac{1}{n}$$
diverges.

Answer (score 1):

Or still simpler, with *equivalences*, since it is a series with positive terms:
$$\frac1{\sqrt{n(n+1)}}\sim_\infty\frac 1n,$$
which diverges, hence the original series diverges.